# Pandas DataFrame stack multiple column values into single column without changing one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, multiple-columns

I'm trying to reshape a data frame in a certain way.

This is the data frame I have,

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| One | *Roxanne* |
| Two | *Ghina* |
| *Roxanne* | *Leila* |
| *Ghina* | *George* |
| Three | *Rock* |
| Four | *Rock* |

I'd like to reshape the dataframe such that it looks like this:

| col_3 |
| --- |
| *Roxanne* |
| *Ghina* |
| *Leila* |
| *George* |
| *Rock* |
| *Rock* |
| One |
| Two |
| Three |
| Four |

How would I go about doing this? *(without changing col_2 values)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For expected ouput join both columns with removed matched values from `col_1` by `col_2`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.col_2, df.loc[~df.col_1.isin(df.col_2), 'col_1']]).to_frame('col_3')
print (df)
     col_3
0  Roxanne
1    Ghina
2    Leila
3   George
4     Rock
5     Rock
0      One
1      Two
4    Three
5     Four
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
out = (df[['col_2', 'col_1']].melt(value_name='col_3')[['col_3']]
       .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Or:

```
out = (df.loc[:, ::-1].unstack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='col_3')
       .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
      )
```

output:

```
     col_3
0  Roxanne
1    Ghina
2    Leila
3   George
4     Rock
5      One
6      Two
7    Three
8     Four
```